# Wordpress Jquery UI Spinner

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery-ui

I am trying to use jquery-ui spinner in my plugin. I had googled it, but not found any referrence that can help me out. It is also not written in the docs http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script. Nor also only the word `spinner`. Is the current version of wordpress (3.8.1) include jquery ui spinner in its library? If so, how to use it on a plugin?

Best Regards :)

Answer (score 3):

Just found it here http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script

Here is an example how to load it on a plugin:

```
function load_jquey_spinner() {
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-ui-spinner' );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_jquey_spinner');
```

Comment: make sure, you also load `jquery` and `jquery-ui-core`

Comment: @FranciscoCorralesMorales - Typically when using core scripts there is no need to declare dependencies, as the scripts are pre-registered with them out of the box; the pre-registered script `jquery-ui-spinner` already has `jquery-ui-core` as a dependency, which in turn has `jquery`.  The main idea of dependencies is for when you register/enqueue custom scripts.